# Mongoose, NODE JS returns undefined but the correct data is collected within the findOne

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Currently trying to get one user's data from my MongoDB database. But the function results in receiving undefined.

```
function getIntro(req){
  user.findOne({ id: req },function (err, person) { 
    if (err){ 
        console.log(err) 
    } 
    else{ 
      console.log(person)
        return person 
    } 
})}
```

The console.log(person) provides me with the expected data so I'd assume that the return also has that data within.

The problem I am running into is where this function resolves to the console.log here comes out as undefined.

```
}
 function getVoiceInfo(userID){
   var user = userController.getIntro(userID);
   console.log('here is the user ' + user)
   voice(user)
}
```

Any help to point me in the correct direction would be amazing.

Comment: Add route and controller completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getIntro` has an error, you can not return a `person` in a callback function.
One of the approaches you can use is `async/await`.
So make your functions `getInvoiceInfo` and `getIntro` `async`
and call `getIntro` with `await`

```
async function getIntro(req){
    try{
      let person = await user.findOne({ id: req });
      return person;
    } catch (err) {
            console.log(err) 
    }
}
    
async function getVoiceInfo(userId) {
    var user = await userController.getIntro(userID);
    console.log('here is the user ' + user)
    voice(user)
}
```

You can use callbacks also, but not the way you did. And for the callback approach (as @Mohammad says) more code is needed.

Comment: Thanks, Boris, I'd tried some other variant with async functions but that area is something I'm still working on getting the hang of. Seemed to have await in the wrong location before. What is the purpose of await in the getVoiceInfo function?

Comment: Basically, async keyword in function definition has two effects: 1. enables to use await inside, and 2. makes it always return a promise. So in order to return a user in getVoiceInfo, await must be used, and again getVoiceInfo must be declared as asnyc